# Conditional formatting of power bi table cell

Tags: excel, switch-statement, google-visualization, powerbi, dax

i have a table for product in power bi. It has a column called sales rate.it has a text value “high,medium,low”.i want to add a conditional formatting to it. If it is high,the background of a cell should be red.if it is medium, background of a cell should be yellow.otherwise it will be green. How i can do it? And is it possible to use switch function with text?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Sounds like the answer is to just do what you said. What is the problem?

Comment: Please read this handy guide to get better answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can make a new column, like this:

```
Column = SWITCH('Table'[Sales rate]; "high"; "red"; "medium"; "yellow"; "low"; "green")
```

Then right click each of the fields in Visualizations pane and select `Conditional formatting` -> `Background color`:

[image]

Format it by `Field value`, based on the column made, with `First` summarization, and you will get the highlighting you want:

[image]

See [Use conditional formatting in tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-conditional-table-formatting) for more information.